# how can i setState to change selectOption by React Select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I need custom form effects
I want to be able to only click the custom range label, the select form will not close,
When I'm done with the other steps, go to change and turn the select off,
Which parameter should I use?

Expected effect map
[image]

I try to check props docs, but i haven't see about this effect settings.

[props](https://react-select.com/props)

Comment: You can handle close when user select any option by props.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this props closeMenuOnSelect props.

Try this on your select component:
**closeMenuOnSelect={false}**